# Copy-Item no target directory

Tags: powershell, command-line, scripting, idempotent

Say you have this folder

```
foo
```

You can run this command in Bash

```
cp -r --no-target-directory foo bar
```

and it will create

```c
foo
bar # same contents as foo
```

Then you can re-run the command without changing the result. How can you do this with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that

```
cp -r -fo foo bar
```

only works if `bar` does not exist and

```
cp -r -fo foo/* bar
```

only works if `bar` exists. So to work around, you need to make sure `bar` exists before doing anything

```
md -f bar
cp -r -fo foo/* bar
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do that. It will create the `bar` folder, which will contain everything that `foo` contains.

```
copy-item .\foo .\bar -recurse -force
```